# Deploy or Publish iOS app on iStore using Smartface IDE without Mac

Tags: smartface.io

Is it possible to Publish iOS app on iStore using Smartface IDE without Mac?

If so then please send me details for the same.

Regards,
Suyog

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the iOS publish with Xcode. 
So, you should have a mac or at least you should have a virtual mac in order to send your application to Apple Store.